# Best way to control around 250 LEDs

Tags: arduino, led, raspberry-pi

I have got the task of coming up with a solution of individually controlling around 250 LEDs. As I would be a complete newcomer in programming an Arduino or whatever else there is, the computing platform is relatively irrelevant for this job (*). It mainly should be portable and not overly large.

The LEDs could be single colour but if there is a simple extension for RGB LEDs, this might be even better. If there is a hard limit in controlling such a number of LEDs and things would be much easier if we reduced this number, we might be able to put three or at most four LEDs on the same controller. (The LEDs will be behind a screen and not directly seen.) In that case, the number might be around 80.

The question is mostly about what would be the best platform choice in this case?

(*): I am mainly a programmer and not an electrical engineer, so diving into a C like library is my least problem. Hardware is my problem.

**Edit:** The LEDs should be variably positioned. There may be smaller clusters or strings of a few LEDs but otherwise it should be rather arbitrary. There should be ~< 2m between the outmost LEDs.

Comment: What's the layout of this design? Will they be in strings?

Comment: Ah, forgot to mention. See edit.

Comment: Charlieplexing?

Comment: This question isn't off-topic because it asks for a the best way to control 250 LEDS, using hardware, without regard to a perticular machine.

Answer (score 2):

What's the budget?  Do you already have the LEDs?

For that many, I'd probably try to use some "neopixels" (LEDs with WS2812 or similar controller).  It can make the wiring much simpler by allowing daisy chain.  And you can stick on multiple power supplies if you need based on the number of LEDs and the brightness.

You only need one data pin if they're all in one string

Comment: Not sure WS2812 strings can be as long as 250 items, but by splitting it into 2 or 3 strings, this answer yields the simplest and most practical solution, to my mind.

Comment: Should be no problem (if power is sufficient).  Here's a video of someone driving 1000+. http://wp.josh.com/2014/05/13/ws2812-neopixels-are-not-so-finicky-once-you-get-to-know-them/

Comment: Neither programming hardware nor LEDs have been bought. Of course we’re aiming for a cheap solution; I guess up to a few hundred € would be fine (and the less soldering work there is to do the better).

Comment: The main drawback to neopixels is cost.  Since each has an onboard chip, it's more expensive than just a bare LED.  But you get to weigh that against the complexity and hardware you'd need to wire up LEDs individually by other methods.  Strips of LEDs are the common way to get them, but you can cut the strips into shorter segments yourself, or you can get them in individual packages.

Answer (score 1):

You can stick to your Arduino but you need some extra electronics to handle all the I/O. Your Arduino is excellent at sending out serial data, but have a limited amount of outputs to handle parallell data. So you could use some kind of serial to parallell register. Like a shift register: 74HC595.

Check out [this](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-a-24X6-LED-matrix/?ALLSTEPS) link to a straightforward serial to parallell, rows and columns arrangement. That solution could probably be scaled to fit your needs, except for the RGB thing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method out there that many people use in those giant LED cubes. Essentially what you do is wire the LEDs in a grid fashion. On the X axis (Vertically) you will have all the ground pins of the LEDs connected. On the Y axis (Horizontally) you would have all the positive LED pins connected. You will end up with each columns' grounds connected, and each rows' positive pins connected. You can use shift registers to turn on and off a columns' ground, and the rows' positive. You get a coordinate system. This is the method that uses the least components and pins. You then could move the LEDs around through out your project, as long as the wiring stays the same.

Example:

Column 1's ground is turned on. Row 3's positive is turned on. You get the LED (1, 3) to turn on.